# How do I block a destination url via routing in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, seo, action, router

I have a basic routing in Zend like:

- url -> /faq (Controller Faq, default Action index)
- url -> /faq/index (Controller Faq, Action index)

This url deserve the same content, a duplicate content (SEO) and I would like to block the url /faq/index and throw a 404.

If someone know how to do that... THX !

Comment: I found a solution with Apache Url Rewriting like this:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/index http://domain.tld/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

But if there is a solution directly in Zend, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use router ([Zend_Controller_Front](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.front.html)):

```
// add to your Route file
    $Router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter(); 
    $Router->addRoute('frotendPage', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
       '/faq', array(
          'module' => 'frontend',
          'controller' => 'page',
          'action' => 'faq')
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
if ($this->_request->getActionName() == 'index') {
            throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception;
        }
}
```

but it's always situation dependent.